# Detect if "Bluetooth scanning" for location is turned on

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-location

Since Android M it is possible to scan for Bluetooth devices in the background even if the global location is turned off if you have enabled the **Bluetooth scanning** option in location settings (see screenshot).

In order to scan for BLE devices, the following conditions must be met:

- `COARSE_LOCATION` or `FINE_LOCATION` permission granted.

And one of the following:

- Global Location selector enabled.
- **Bluetooth scanning** option enabled (see screenshot).

I can check that the permission is granted and the state of the location selector just fine. What I haven't been able to do is figure out **how to check the state of the `Bluetooth Scanning` option?**

Any insights are much appreciated!

[image: Marshmallow Bluetooth Scanning Option]

Comment: I'm very interested in how to detect the state, too. Because when this is turned on, our BLE connection makes trouble on some devices...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of search, I finally found a way to know the state:

```
try {
    ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    int result = Settings.Global.getInt(resolver,"ble_scan_always_enabled");
    if(result == 1) {
        // Bluetooth scanning is on
    } else {
        // Bluetooth scanning is off
    }
} catch(SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // Settings doesn't exist, on Android < 6
}
```

You can also use `"wifi_scan_always_enabled"` to get wifi scanning state.
It doesn't require any permissions.

I will update this post if I find a way to redirect the user to the screen or to disable it.

Comment: Does not work for me on on android Q. `"ble_scan_always_enabled"` cannot be found

Comment: @apex39 you can also use "WifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable()" to get wifi scanning state.

Comment: For people getting `SettingNotFoundException` - try toggling WiFi & Bluetooth scanning on/off in Settings and run your code again.