# Is there a way to detect if “Bluetooth scanning” for location is turned on using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

It's basically the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004377/detect-if-bluetooth-scanning-for-location-is-turned-on) but on expo.

I checked expo documentation and don't find anything about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if "Bluetooth scanning" for location is turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004377/detect-if-bluetooth-scanning-for-location-is-turned-on)

Comment: no, this show how to detect it on pure android and i use expo framework for react native. I searched on expo documentation and don't find anything about it. If expo does not do it, i will need eject my application and do it myself, like this other stack is showing.